# How to format a cell to auto-highlight a date that is in the past

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find a way to auto-highlight a cell in a specific color if the date entered in the cell is in the past compared to today's date.

If today's date is 4/26 and I enter 4/23 into the cell, it should be auto-highlighted because the date entered in the cell is in the past. I have a spreadsheet that has multiple dates that I, at the moment, manually highlight. I want them automatically highlighted once the date is in the past.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Conditional Formatting to highlight cells based on their content.

Select the cell that contain the dates, then select *Conditional Formatting|Highlight Cells Rules|Less Than...* on the Home tab of the ribbon.

[image]

In the dialog box enter `=today()`

[image]

This will highlight the cells containing dates that are before today.